# how to insert value in hex file using srec_cat

Tags: hex, srec-cat

I have a value say 0xAABBCCDD that I want to add to a hex file at a known address. I have not found an srec_cat option to do this yet, is this possible?

Comment: Is there a tool out there that can do this?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible by combination of `srec_cat` commands.
Let `in.hex` be input file, `out.hex` be output file, `0x64` is the address to place 4-byte value so that the value will occupy addresses from `0x64` to `0x67` (`0x68` is the first address after the value).

```
srec_cat in.hex -I -E 0x64 0x68 -GEN 0x64 0x68 -LECONST 0xAABBCCDD 4 -O out.hex -I
```

Step by step:

```
in.hex -I
```

read input file `in.hex`, format **I**ntel hex

```
-E 0x64 0x68
```

apply filter **E**xclude—remove (if any) data in range `64` (including) — `0x68` (excluding)

```
-GEN 0x64 0x68
```

**GEN**erate content for address range `0x64` (including) — `0x68` (excluding)

```
-LECONST 0xAABBCCDD 4
```

the content is **L**ittle **E**ndian **CONST**ant `0xAABBCCDD` with width `4` bytes.

```
-O out.hex -I
```

write **O**ut result data.

p.s. See [srec_cat](http://srecord.sourceforge.net/man/man1/srec_cat.html) and [srec_input](http://srecord.sourceforge.net/man/man1/srec_input.html) (for filter description)